# Specify model ID when declaring attributes in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a model representing the branches of a franchise in django.

Here is how I'm declaring the model:

```
class Branch(models.Model):
"""
Branch/Outlet of a franchise in a city
"""
city_id = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
address = models.CharField(max_length=220, null=False)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
# An array of Ids of nearby branches sorted in order of distance
nearby_branches = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False))
```

Is it possible to specify `nearby_branches` as a list of Ids of the branch model instead of a charfield as I've done here.

eg. something like `nearby_branches = ArrayField(Branch.id)`

Comment: Nearby branch names or id's would be passed by you while creating an object and saving it to the database

Comment: @Exprator Yes it would. My question is more along the lines of whether it is possible to reference the Branch model's ID as opposed to using `models.Charfield` ?

Comment: That depends on you, either you can use an IntegerField or charfield. or a key value pair type

Comment: @Exprator an IntegerField seems like a more solid bet here. thanks for your help.

Comment: You can follow this answer